# Laravel 5 Custom Validator resolver not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hi Guys I would like to register my new CustomValidator class. This contains some validation for a mobile number I created this class

```
<?php

// This class is located in App\Validator
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator {

    public function validateIsKyc($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        return $value == 'is_kyc';
    }


}
```

Now in my AppServiceProvider here's my code for loading that class

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {       
        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And on my request I tried using the custom validation like so

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateRegistrationRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'phone_no'  => "required|isKyc",
        ];
    }
}
```

But I get this error

```
FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 23: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::resolver()
```

Don't know what went wrong any idea please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `App\Validator\CustomValidator.php` you need to add at the beginning

```
<?php namespace App\Validator;
```

In the file `AppServiceProvider.php` you need to add at the beginning

```
use App\Validator\CustomValidator;
```

and also replace this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
```

with this

```
use Validator;
```

Comment: Wow this is great. Works like a charm :D I still need to study what happen and what did I miss. I'm kinda new with laravel and I need to understand this implementation. Thanks again for this

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys,

I already know the solution, i doing something wrong, i wasn't aware im putting my code into the register function instead to boot() function.

From

```
    public function register()
    {
        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    }
```

to this,

```
    public function register()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }
```

now i can manage my customvalidators to one class only. :)

**GGWP Laravel!**